# Constrain union T in different branches

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to inspect what a generic unioned type is within the body of a method?

For example, I have

```
const stringIdentity = (original: string): string => {
    return original
}
const numIdentity = (original: number): number => {
    return original
}

const identity = <T = string | number>(original: T): T => {
    if (typeof original === 'string') {
        return stringIdentity(original) // <-- error on this line
    } 
    if (typeof original === 'number') {
        return numIdentity(original)    // <-- error on this line
    }
}
```

Playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20identity%20%3D%20%3CT%20%3D%20string%20%7C%20number%3E(original%3A%20T)%3A%20T%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20original%20%3D%3D%3D%20'string')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20stringIdentity(original)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20original%20%3D%3D%3D%20'number')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20numIdentity(original)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20stringIdentity%20%3D%20(original%3A%20string)%3A%20string%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20original%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20numIdentity%20%3D%20(original%3A%20number)%3A%20number%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20original%0D%0A%7D).

In each of the branches I get an error*

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'

As a human, I can see that `T` is a string in the top branch and that I should be able to return a string safely. Is there a way to convince the compiler of this?

---

<sup>*or "Type 'number'..."</sup>

Comment: Here in your identity function, what if I pass the object, neither string nor number. If you have marked the return type of identity function as T, so you have to handle all the possible types. Your identity function returning void on the given type of object

Answer (score 1):

The error is correct. You could for example call your function with `T` being `string & {x: number}`, it might make no sense but it is possible. Then the `typeof` condition will return true, but the result of `stringIdentity` will be of type `string`, but not `T`.

One solution would be to convert your identity functions so that they are generic, too. Another solution would be to just add a cast because anyone using `string & {x: number}` as `T` is not very probable.

But what I guess is really the case is that you simplified your real problem in order to make it into a StackOverflow question, but you simplified too much probably, and now it's not very clear what is your real setup. Are you really operating on strings and numbers or not?

Comment: Interesting. Sounds like the types are not as simple as I original thought (again). The real problem isn't too much more complicated: I have a map of strings to either strings or nested maps.

Answer (score 1):

**You can achieve this as follows:**

```js
    const identity = <T = string | number>(original: T): typeof original => {
        if (typeof original === 'string') {
            return stringIdentity(original) as typeof original;
        } 
        if (typeof original === 'number') {
            return numIdentity(original) as typeof original;
        }
    }

    const stringIdentity = (original: string): string => {
        return original
    }

    const numIdentity = (original: number): number => {
        return original
    }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20identity%20%3D%20%3CT%20%3D%20string%20%7C%20number%3E(original%3A%20T)%3A%20T%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20original%20%3D%3D%3D%20'string')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20stringIdentity(original)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20original%20%3D%3D%3D%20'number')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20numIdentity(original)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20stringIdentity%20%3D%20(original%3A%20string)%3A%20string%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20original%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20numIdentity%20%3D%20(original%3A%20number)%3A%20number%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20original%0D%0A%7D)

> Warning: Here in your identity function, what if I pass the object, neither string nor number. If you have marked the return type of identity function as T, so you have to handle all the possible types. Your identity function returning void on the given type of object.